# ADB backup and pull commands create no files on PC

Tags: android, backup, adb

Android 5.1.1 on Sony Xperia Z1, not rooted
ADB ("Minimal ADB and Fastboot") on Windows 8

Hello knowledgeable people,

I am on the way to root my Xperia Z1 for the first time and am trying to use "Minimal ADB and Fastboot" to backup my phone using an ADB command like

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all c:\XperiaBackup20160618.ab
```

All steps in the process go well ...

- ADB recognizes the device,
- I get to see all screens I'm supposed to see,
- I see the files being backed up on my phone screen during the process,
- the time the process takes is appropriate

... except that no backup file shows up on my computer. Not even a 0 KB one, like I read elsewhere.

After trying to find it literally everywhere manually and with Windows search, I checked whether ADB is sandboxed by my Comodo Internet Security (it is not for all I can see).

To see if something else works, I then tried pulling only my SD card using ADB pull, but got the same result: The process runs smoothly, progress percentage ticks steadily up in the command prompt and the file names copied are shown, but in the end I have no files nowhere.

What am I missing ...?

(Note, I read that problems between certain ADB versions and PC systems can be solved by downloading alternative releases of the Android SDK, but I prefer not to download a 1 GB suite just for backing up my phone. I'll do it, though, if you guys say it'll work then.)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure the terminal was opened in the right folder? When you open the command prompt go to a directory with `cd` for example: `cd C:/` then execute an adb command, for example: `adb pull -p /sdcard/file.zip`. The downloaded file should be now in `C:/`

Comment: Thank you, A. Omar, I guess I just figured -- seems I was missing the '-f' before the file location in my command ...

Comment: Haha that awkward moment :p You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is: Write your command well!

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all -f c:\XperiaBackup20160618.ab
```

Little '-f' makes all the difference.